# JQuery Validation not picking up custom messages

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have the following function, but when the validation is triggered, it is displaying the stock "This field is required." message, not my custom message.

```
     $('#customerEnquiry')
  .validate({ // initialize the plugin
      rules: {
          "InputModel.FirstName":
              {
                  required: true
              },
          "InputModel.Surname": {
              required: true,
              minlength: 3
          },
          messages: {
              "InputModel.FirstName":
                  {
                      required: "Please Supply First Name (or initial)."
                  },
              "InputModel.Surname": {
                  required: "Please Supply Surname.",
                  minlength: "Minimum length of 3."
              }
          }
      }
  });
```

There are no errors in the console, so I am at a loss as to why the messages are not being triggered. The only obvious thing I can see is that the error labels that are auto generated are not picking up the full name of the tested control. (As shown below)

```
<label class="error" for="Surname" generated="true">This field is required.</label>
```

Being as my html is generated automatically, and is data bound to my model, I have no control over the naming of the input controls.

So is there any way I can get round this, or do I need to go back to fighting with Microsofts unobtrusive validation, which gives me the correct labels, but doesn't let me do other things I wish to achieve.

Below is a snip of the relevant HTML

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="basic-tab">
```

```
<div class="control-group">

  <label class="control-label" for="InputModel_FirstName">Customer Forename (or Initial)</label>

    <div class="controls">

      <input name="InputModel.FirstName" class="noltmarg" id="FirstName" type="text" placeholder="Enter First name" value="" data-val-required="First Name is required" data-val="true">

    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="InputModel_Surname">Customer Surname</label>

    <div class="controls">
      <input name="InputModel.Surname" class="noltmarg" id="Surname" type="text" placeholder="Enter Surname" value="" data-val-required="Surname is required" data-val="true" data-val-length-min="2" data-val-length-max="30" data-val-length="At Least 2 Letters are Required">

    </div>
</div>

    ... Rest of form omitted for Brevity
</fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: is it working with "minlength" condition ?

Comment: No, that is returning the default message as well.

Comment: If the input contains an attribute, `name="InputModel.FirstName"`, then it should be working.  Otherwise, we need to see the proper amount of code for a working demo, which would include showing us the relevant ***rendered*** HTML markup.

Comment: *"I have no control over the naming of the input controls."* ~ but you have control over the JavaScript.  In other words, look at the rendered HTML output and construct your `.validate()` method accordingly.

Comment: I think Sparky is right, your field name should same as your rule selector.

Comment: The javascript is. the names are typically "InputModel.Surname", which si what is in the javascript. However, when the validation is triggered, the name of the displayed fields for the resultant error messages do not match the fields. These error message labels are auto generated by the validation framework.

Comment: @Sparky Rendered HTML has been added. This is my first time using Jquery.validate() so apologies if it is something obvious I am missing

Comment: You've messed up your braces and incorrectly placed `messages` inside of `rules`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misplaced a bracket effectively placing `messages` inside the `rules` object...

```
$('#customerEnquiry').validate({ // initialize the plugin
    rules: {
        "InputModel.FirstName": {
            required: true
        },
        "InputModel.Surname": {
            required: true,
            minlength: 3
        },
        messages: {
            "InputModel.FirstName": {
                required: "Please Supply First Name (or initial)."
            },
            "InputModel.Surname": {
                required: "Please Supply Surname.",
                minlength: "Minimum length of 3."
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Instead, `messages` is supposed to be a sibling of `rules`...

```
$('#customerEnquiry').validate({ // initialize the plugin
    rules: {
        // 
    },
    messages: {
        //      
    }
});
```

**DEMO: [jsfiddle.net/gLruabce/](https://jsfiddle.net/gLruabce/)**